# htaccess files redirects images and css file

Tags: css, image, .htaccess, redirect

I am using .htacess file to redirect my pages with this script:

```
*#domain/page/about 
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)?$  detail.php?tag=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)?$  detail.php?tag=$1 [NC]*

#domain/about 
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$  detail.php?tag=$1 [NC]
```

The script is working fine but when I use:

```
#domain/about 
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$  detail.php?tag=$1 [NC]
```

all my images, jscripts, and css files are disabled.

I know its due to the above script but can I tell the .htaccess file to ignore .css, .jpg files from redirection or put same where they are?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php/?)(.*)$  detail.php?tag=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This line will prevent redirection for css, js and image files.

Also remember to add `L` flag in your RewriteRule to mark it as **Last** rule.

Comment: thanks it worked but now my index file also redirected to detail.php.

Comment: Well that problem of index.php redirecting existed even before my suggestion. However pls try updated code in my answer.